# primefaces calendar se queda flotando

Tags: java, primefaces

### Problema

Tengo una plantilla en [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) y para una vista en particular, agregué un `<p:calendar>` dentro de un `<div>`.

Al dar click en el campo se muestra el calendario, pero al girar la rueda del mouse, el panel con el calendrio flota y se mueve en conjunto con el desplazamiento de la página, en vez de permanecer con el campo al que pertenece.

[image: error pcalendar]

### Código

```
<ui:define name="CONTENT">
  <h:form id="formTabla">
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="formTabla:txt_fecha" value="Fecha">
        <p:calendar id="txt_fecha" required="true"
            autocomplete="off" value="#{controlador.fecha}"
            readonlyInput="true" locale="es" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy">
          <p:ajax update="txt_fecha Message_txt_fecha" event="dateSelect" />
        </p:calendar>
        <p:message id="Message_txt_fecha" for="txt_fecha" />
    </div>
```

### Especificaciones técnicas

- PrimeFaces 6.0
- JBoss EAP 6.2

### Algunas preguntas relacionadas que ya he revisado

- [Floating p:calendar when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402811/floating-pcalendar-when-scrolling?noredirect=1#comment64313266_38402811)
- [p:selectOneMenu dropdown part scrolls and does not stay in position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Cualquier retroalimentación o ayuda es bienvenida.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me suena a que puede ser un tema de tus css que esten teniendo un conflicto con el que le asigna primefaces.

Comment: Sin duda es un tema de css, pero tambien puede ser un tema de navegador, que navegador estas utilizando?

Comment: chrome 53.0.2785.116 m

Answer (score 0):

En principio no es necesario actualizar el componente ***p:calendar*** a sí mismo, ni tampoco debes actualizar el ***p:message***, hacer eso puede generar gran cantidad de inconsistencias.

Por otra parte, utiliza la etiqueta ***p:outputLabel*** de la siguiente manera para tener mejor consistencia entre tus componentes.

```
<p:outputLabel for="txt_fecha" value="Fecha" />
```

Chécate este video donde puedes aprender 3 técnicas para actualizar correctamente tus componentes:

https://youtu.be/hooHODgu6aM

Saludos!